# How to fix Conversion from Pine 4 to 5 Error?

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to convert everget's obv indicator from pine 4 to 5 with the auto-convert feature on tradingview, but it gives me this error:

Conversion failed, reason: line 10: line 16: 'obv' is already defined.

```
Line 10: signalType = input(title="Signal Smoothing Type", defval="SMA", options=["EMA", "SMA"])
Line 16: obv = cum(sign(change(src)) * volume)
```

How do I fix this?

```
//@version=4
//On Balance Volume by everget, Oct 29, 2018

//Copyright (c) 2018-present, Alex Orekhov (everget)
//On Balance Volume script may be freely distributed under the MIT license.

study("On Balance Volume", shorttitle="OBV", precision=0)

showSignal = input(title="Show Signal ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)
signalType = input(title="Signal Smoothing Type", defval="SMA", options=["EMA", "SMA"])
signalLength = input(title="Signal Smoothing Length", type=input.integer, defval=21)
highlightCrossovers = input(title="Highlight Crossovers ?", type=input.bool, defval=false)
applyFilling = input(title="Apply Ribbon Filling ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)
src = input(title="Source", type=input.source, defval=close)

obv = cum(sign(change(src)) * volume)
ema_1 = ema(obv, signalLength)
sma_1 = sma(obv, signalLength)
signal = signalType == "EMA" ? ema_1 : sma_1

trendColor = obv > signal ? #0ebb23 : color.red

obvColor = applyFilling ? trendColor : #0094ff
signalColor = applyFilling ? trendColor : #ff6a00

obvPlot = plot(obv, title="OBV", linewidth=2, color=obvColor, transp=0)
signalPlot = plot(showSignal ? signal : na, title="Signal", color=signalColor, transp=0)

transparent = color.new(color.white, 100)

fillColor = applyFilling ? trendColor : transparent
fill(obvPlot, signalPlot, color=fillColor, transp=70)

plotshape(crossover(obv, signal) and highlightCrossovers ? obv : na, title="Crossover", location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=color.green, transp=0)
plotshape(crossunder(obv, signal) and highlightCrossovers ? obv : na, title="Crossunder", location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=color.red, transp=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`obv` is a built-in variable name, so use another name.

```
//@version=4
//On Balance Volume by everget, Oct 29, 2018

//Copyright (c) 2018-present, Alex Orekhov (everget)
//On Balance Volume script may be freely distributed under the MIT license.

study("On Balance Volume", shorttitle="obv", precision=0)

showSignal = input(title="Show Signal ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)
signalType = input(title="Signal Smoothing Type", defval="SMA", options=["EMA", "SMA"])
signalLength = input(title="Signal Smoothing Length", type=input.integer, defval=21)
highlightCrossovers = input(title="Highlight Crossovers ?", type=input.bool, defval=false)
applyFilling = input(title="Apply Ribbon Filling ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)
src = input(title="Source", type=input.source, defval=close)

_obv = cum(sign(change(src)) * volume)
ema_1 = ema(_obv, signalLength)
sma_1 = sma(_obv, signalLength)
signal = signalType == "EMA" ? ema_1 : sma_1

trendColor = _obv > signal ? #0ebb23 : color.red

_obvColor = applyFilling ? trendColor : #0094ff
signalColor = applyFilling ? trendColor : #ff6a00

_obvPlot = plot(_obv, title="obv", linewidth=2, color=_obvColor, transp=0)
signalPlot = plot(showSignal ? signal : na, title="Signal", color=signalColor, transp=0)

transparent = color.new(color.white, 100)

fillColor = applyFilling ? trendColor : transparent
fill(_obvPlot, signalPlot, color=fillColor, transp=70)

plotshape(crossover(_obv, signal) and highlightCrossovers ? _obv : na, title="Crossover", location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=color.green, transp=0)
plotshape(crossunder(_obv, signal) and highlightCrossovers ? _obv : na, title="Crossunder", location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=color.red, transp=0)
```